# Outlook 2019 automaticaly preview attached document on select

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment, preview

everyone,

i have little or no experience with vba and am currently trying to solve the following problem:

When selecting an e-mail in the inbox, the preview of the attachment should be displayed immediately.

I have already found out that there is an Event Listener which allows me to intercept the selection of an item. Now I just have to preview the attachment somehow. Does anyone have a hint for me if such a function exists and if so where it is documented?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to preview any attachment, if the email is selected? Could that not cause security issues?

Comment: Exactly, e-mails sent internally from a fax printer end up in this inbox having the message attached as a pdf, so my plan was to check the From before previewing

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for selecting the attached file. But you can handle the selection-related events:

- [AttachmentSelectionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.attachmentselectionchange?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm3483)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) is fired when the user selects a different or additional attachment in the active explorer programmatically or by interacting with the user interface.
- [BeforeAttachmentPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.BeforeAttachmentPreview) is fired before an attachment associated with an instance of the parent object is previewed.